# Objective-C: Variable won't get used (if)

Tags: objective-c, variables, if-statement

I'm using a pretty simple if-clause which just checks a name an should give back a variable, but it doesnt get recognized.
the "createUser" variable is marked as unused.

```
NSString *salesPersonName = [[[SevdeskApiManager sharedManager] currentSevUser] firstName];
    if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXX "]) {
        NSString *createUser = @"1";
    } else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXX"]) {
        NSString *createUser = @"11";
    } else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXXX"]) {
        NSString *createUser = @"111";
    } else {
        NSString *createUser = @"1111";
    }
    // Hier die keyvalues eintragen
    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=nachtelefonieren&assigned[id]%@=&assigned[objectName]=SevUser&category[id]=31&category[objectName]=Category& createUser[id]=%@&createUser[objectName]=SevUser&noticeCreator=0&deadline=%@&status=100&object[id]=28243&object[objectName]=SevClient",assignedUser,createUser,deadline];
```

Comment: You're creating three completely independent variables named `createUser` that aren't used within their scope, and the compiler warns you accordingly. These variables shadow your existing `createUser` variable, otherwise you'd get an "unknown identifier" compiler error in the last line of your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your variable declaration outside the scope of each `if` (right now the variable is created & discarded immediately)

```
NSString *createUser;

if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXX "]) {
    createUser = @"1";
} else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXX"]) {
    createUser = @"11";
} else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXXX"]) {
    createUser = @"111";
} else {
    createUser = @"1111";
}
```

Also, instead of a multi-if statement, you could use a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"XXX " : @"1",
    @"XXXX" : @"11",
    @"XXXXX" : @"111"
};

NSString *createUser = dict[salesPersonName] ?: @"1111";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just declare the `createUser` instance variable **outside** of the if-block scope (i.e. similar to your declaration of `salesPersonName`). This should reduce redundancy in your code and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the instance variable outside of the if-block and init it with an empty value, because it could crash the program at bodyString variable line.

```
NSString *createUser = @"";
if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXX "]) {
    createUser = @"1";
} else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXX"]) {
    createUser = @"11";
} else if ([salesPersonName isEqual: @"XXXXX"]) {
    createUser = @"111";
} else {
    createUser = @"1111";
}

// Hier die keyvalues eintragen
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=nachtelefonieren&assigned[id]%@=&assigned[objectName]=SevUser&category[id]=31&category[objectName]=Category& createUser[id]=%@&createUser[objectName]=SevUser&noticeCreator=0&deadline=%@&status=100&object[id]=28243&object[objectName]=SevClient",assignedUser,createUser,deadline];
```